# How to get file content and move file to different Google Cloud Storage using Google Cloud functions

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-functions, python-3.7

I'm trying to get the file that was uploaded to Google Cloud Storage, do some work with its content, and move it to a different bucket using Google Cloud Functions with python3.7. Following their documentation I was only able to get file name. I tried using `import cloudstorage` but it errors `module 'cloudstorage' has no attribute 'NotFoundError'`, and googling did not get me anywhere.

Does any one have a sample code that could do what I need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `cloudstorage` library is specific to the [Standard environment of App Engine](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/googlecloudstorageclient/read-write-to-cloud-storage).

A library compatible with Cloud Storage would be [`google-cloud-storage`](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/reference/libraries#client-libraries-install-python). You must declare it in your `requirements.txt` file for your function.

[This example](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/renaming-copying-moving-objects#storage-copy-object-python) on how to copy from one bucket to another should suffice. After copying it, you can just do `source_blob.delete()` to get rid of it.